# Build args does not pass in value to docker file

Tags: java, linux, docker, build, alpine-linux

I want to build a docker image. And I run

```
docker build --build-arg project_file_name=account.jar -t account:1.0 .
```

The docker file looks like this (#1)

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8u172b11_server-jre

ARG project_file_name

MAINTAINER jim
COPY src/${project_file_name} /home/${project_file_name}
CMD java -jar /home/${project_file_name}
```

If hardcode the variable, it will look like this (#2)

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8u172b11_server-jre

MAINTAINER jim
enter code here
COPY src/account.jar /home/account.jar
CMD java -jar /home/account.jar
```

After I build the image with #1 and #2

Using #1, when I docker run, docker tell me it cannot find the specified jar file

Using #2, when I docker run, docker is able to execute the java jar file correctly.

To me both #1 and #2 are same. Just #1 use build-arg variable way and #2 is hardcoding the value. I believe the way I use build-args is incorrect. Can anyone guide me on this?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A running container won’t have access to an `ARG` variable value., you'll need `ENV` variable for that. Though you can use `ARG` variable to set `ENV` variable. In your situation you can do

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8u172b11_server-jre
ARG project_file_name
ENV PROJECT_FILE=${project_file_name}

MAINTAINER jim
COPY src/${project_file_name} /home/${project_file_name}
CMD java -jar /home/${PROJECT_FILE}
```

You can read more [here](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-vs-env/)